# auto expand background height with textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a background to expand automatically when the entered text resizes a textarea. I had problems with the position of the textarea so I had to use position:absolute to place it correctly.

the html:

```
<ul id="UL">
    <li class="newComment_row">
        <div class="userComments_photo">
            <img class="photo" src="' . $userComment_img . '" alt="" />
        </div>
        <textarea id="" class="textarea" rows="1" placeholder="Escribe un comentario..." title="Escribe un comentario..."></textarea>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the css:

```
#UL {
    width: 494px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(225, 226, 227);
}
.newComment_row {
    height: 32px;
    position: relative;
    width: 470px;
    background: rgb(246, 247, 248) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px 12px;
    padding: 4px 0px 8px;
    rows: 1px;
}
.textarea {
    resize: none;
    width: 420px;
    font: normal normal normal 12px/15.3599996566772px Helvetica, Arial, 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px 3px 0 3px;
    margin: 0 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the jquery to autoresize the textarea:

```
function h(e) {
    $(e).css({
        'height': 'auto',
            'overflow-y': 'hidden'
    }).height(e.scrollHeight);
}
$('textarea').each(function () {
    h(this);
}).on('input', function () {
    h(this);
});
```

I'm testing it here http://jsfiddle.net/ttwbxwon/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just optimize the CSS a little...

The textarea doesn't have to be set to `position: absolute`, instead just reduce the width a little. And instead of defining the height of `.newComment_row`, just adjust the bottom padding, so that it's "naturally" as high as you want it to be. Here's what I would add:

```
.textarea {
    width: 416px;
    position: initial;
}
.newComment_row {
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/une6ya96/

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line to the function h

`$(e).parent().height($(e).height());`

You can see it here
http://jsfiddle.net/ttwbxwon/29/

Comment: It breaks the style a little. Anyways, thanks for your answer +1 :)

Comment: You can add +n for more pixels for the parent :) `$(e).parent().height($(e).height()+5);`

Comment: Right! but my problem was a css error and it's already fixed. Thanks!